# Join two files with date and time into a matrix

Tags: bash, join, awk

I have two files with data and different date and time steps and I'd like to merge them into one file or matrix using awk, join or similar as shown in the following example:

First file: File1.txt

```
29.09.2016;01:10:32;4.01
29.09.2016;01:12:58;4.35
```

Second file: File2.txt

```
29.09.2016;01:11:01;8.81
29.09.2016;01:15:58;9.02
```

Output: Matrix.txt

```
29.09.2016;01:10:32;4.01;-
29.09.2016;01:11:01;-;8.81
29.09.2016;01:12:58;4.35;-
29.09.2016;01:15:58;-;9.02
```

How can I do that? How does it work with three data files? Thank you very much.

Comment: you can start by saying what you tried

Comment: How does the `29.09.2016;01:11:01;8.81` line get an extra `-` in the final output file?

Comment: wrt `How does it work with three data files?` - if you have 3 data files then show 3 data files, not 2, as solutions for 2 input streams are usually quite different than for 1 and solutions for 3 or more quite different than for 2. If there can be any overlap of dates/times across the files then show that too. [edit] your question to fix your sample input/output to be more truly representative and add what you have tried so far.

Comment: I removed my answer as I was unclear on the requirements. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`sort` and column control with a couple of `sed`s:

```
$ sort <(sed 's/;/;-;/2' file2.txt ) <(sed 's/$/;-/' file1.txt)
29.09.2016;01:10:32;4.01;-
29.09.2016;01:11:01;-;8.81
29.09.2016;01:12:58;4.35;-
29.09.2016;01:15:58;-;9.02
```

`sort` probably needs parameters do deal with data ordering: `-t\. -k3.1n -k2.1n -k1.1n`.